# Cloudflare's Websocket Performance while "Proxying"

Tags: cloudflare

After finding out that `cloudfare` now supports [Websockets](https://www.cloudflare.com/websockets/). While browsing their [documentation](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169466-Can-I-use-CloudFlare-with-WebSockets-), finding this quote is worrying:

> No additional configuration is required to send WebSockets traffic through CloudFlare. CloudFlare will immediately begin ***proxying*** your WebSockets through to your origin.

- Does this mean each Websocket packet is proxied (thus, increasing latency for games / bi-directional communication), or only the ***initial*** connection?

Comment: I'd imagine the entire connection (you wouldn't want to reveal your server's actual IP to a DDOS attacker, for example). This won't necessarily be a latency hit - it may actually help. That's the theory behind https://www.cloudflare.com/railgun/, after all.

Answer (score 1):

CloudFlare can work in two modes:

- Their standard mode, which caches and proxies everything. To activate this you go into the DNS screen and turn the orange cloud on
- As a DNS server only. This is orange cloud off, grey cloud.

If the domain you're talking has an orange cloud then all requests go into CloudFlare, then if it needs to fulfill the request externally it makes the connection out, gets the reply, and sends it back to the client. This makes their PageRules possible.